# Problem using jQuery-AJAX to submit form to PHP and display new content in div without refreshing

Tags: php, forms, jquery, pdo

I am trying to use jQuery-AJAX to submit the data in my form to my controller (index.php) where it is processed by PHP and inserted via PDO into the database if valid. Once the code is inserted into the database, the div where the form previously existed should be replaced by the contents of another page (newpage.php). The original page should not be refreshed upon submitting of the form, only the div where the form previously existed should be refreshed. There is a particular problem with my code, although I can't seem to find where the issue is at:

Here is my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function processForm() {
    var action= $('#action').val();
    var data = $('#data').val();
    var dataString = 'action=' + action + '&data=' + data;

$.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: ".",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(){
            $('#content_main').load('newpage.php');
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Here is my HTML: (As a side note, I noticed that when I take the "return false;" out of the HTML, that the form will submit to my database, but the whole page also reloads - and is blank. When I leave the "return false;" in the HTML, the newpage.php loads correctly into the div, but the data does not make it into the database)

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="processForm();return false;">

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="action1" />
    <input type="text" name="data" id="data" />

    <input type="submit" value="CONTINUE TO STEP 2" name="submit" />

</form>
```

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
$action = $_POST['action'];

switch ($action) {
    case 'action1':
        $data = $_POST['data'];

        pdo ($data);

    exit;
}
?>
```

I feel like I am making a silly mistake somewhere, but I just can't put my finger on it. Thanks for any assistance you can provide!

SOLUTION (via Jen):

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function processForm() {
        var dataString = $("#yourForm").serialize();

    $.ajax ({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ".",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(){
            $('#content_main').load('newpage.php');
          }
        });
    return false;
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form id="yourForm">

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="action1" />
    <input type="text" id="data" name="data" />

    <input type="submit" value="CONTINUE TO STEP 2" name="submit" />

</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $action = $_POST['action'];

    switch ($action) {
        case 'action1':
            $data = $_POST['data'];

            pdo ($data);

        exit;
    }
?>
```

What I learned: Use the .serialize() jQuery method if it is an option, as it will save a bunch of time writing out the `var` for each form value and .serialize() does not typically make mistakes sending the info to php.

Comment: Is `pdo function ($action);` a typo/summary? Because otherwise, it's a syntax error....

Comment: Yes, it was a summary (with a typo!). I modified it to pdo($data) from pdo function($action). Good spot, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
 $("#yourForm").submit(function(){


  // Could use just this line and not vars below      
  //dataString = $("#yourForm").serialize(); 

  // vars are being set by selecting inputs by id but id not set in form fields
  var action= $('#action').val(); // value of id='action' 
  var data = $('#data').val();    // value of id='data'
  var dataString = 'action=' + action + '&data=' + data;
  // dataString = 'action=&data=' so nothing is posted to db
  // because input fields cannot be found by id
  // fix by adding id fields to form fields

   $.ajax ({
   type: "POST",
   url: ".",
   data: dataString,
   success: function(){
        $('#content_main').load('newpage.php');
    }
   });
return false; 
});
```

And change the form to (I added the id attributes):

```
<form id="yourForm">
<input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="action1" />
<input type="text" id="data" name="data" id="data" />

<input type="submit" value="CONTINUE TO STEP 2" name="submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: You're welcome. And, I learned something as well...I was unsure about the url: '.' just like BeingSimpler was. I'll have to remember that one.

Comment: Hm...on second glance I may have jumped the gun on this. The data is not saving to the database (the initial change I saw was a reflection of a previous update). Hm...

Comment: I edited the answer so your form fields can be picked up by your PHP page.

Comment: Also, the way you were trying to get the value of your forms fields was off a bit. I put both options in my answer.

Comment: Ok! It worked (for sure this time). Like you had suggested, there was a problem with the way the dataString was written. The change I made was taking out `var action` and `var data` and just using `var datastring = $("#yourForm").serialize();`. Thanks a ton for all your help Jen!!!!

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 The working php is in the OP's question. They were using a switch to apply the `$POST` var of data.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Your form isn't posting. Check the console for the page it's posting to and make sure the path is right to `$.post("../process_form.php",`

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Actually that's not it...you js isn't loading.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need an explanation rather than a fix of code. Here is a brief explanation for the 2 cases:

1. When you take out `return false;` the code will treat your form as a normal HTML form that will be submitted to the server via `action=""`, which leads to nowhere. The Javascript, however, also does its job in this case but because the page is redirected to nowhere, then it turns blank at the end.
2. When you put `return false`; back to the form, the form will catch the event handler and know that this form will be returned FALSE to submit. That's why you can see how your Javascript code does the job. However, one thing you should notice is that your jQuery AJAX function needs to `POST` (or `GET`) to a processing file, not `'.'`

Considering this reply based on no knowledge of your real situation. You need to look back over your code and see how you can edit it. Would be happy to reply if you have any questions.

Hope this small hint helps (:

Comment: Thanks for the response, BeingSimpler. I may not been specific in the post, but I am sending the form information to the index file (my controller), so in the case of taking out the `return false;` the form was being submitted to the index file when I used `action=""`, although it did not know what to display (hence the blank page). The `'.'` will work for sending the `POST` to the index file as well, but not the way I had the rest of code setup. Thanks again for the response.